# use typeshed project to get the type

Tags: python

0

how use typeshed project to get the type, I see the website of typeshed but I didnot understand

for example:

```
import re

x=re.compile()
```

how I can know the type of compile is pattern is there anything I should write to know or only search for re.pyi and search for compile in typeshed? is typeshed contain every type annotation for all modules and what modules does not contain?

Question: how I can know the type of compile--> pattern by using typeshed

Comment: `how I can know the type of compile` → `type(x)`

Comment: @rzlvmp how I can know the type of compile--> pattern by using typeshed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for extra libraries, just read the documentation! For example for `re.compile` this is available on the main Python website:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile

If you have some 3rd-party library and the documentation is poor, check the source code for what it expects. If *both* the source code is very difficult to interpret and also the documentation is poor, don't use the code.